# SQL script execution control

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am looking for tips how to control execution of large sql script. It will contain various DDL and DML statement. Mostly I was looking for DDL control.What do I actually mean is, that basically I have a script with multiple DDL statements that are generated from one of our DBs. When I start script it will go through even if there is compilation error or error on create.
Thx for any ideas

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: its oracle db,using sqlplus(@file.sql) since this would be easier solution

Comment: Please be aware that, depending on the script, some statements will error-out if previous statements also had errors.  For example, indicies and constraints generally can't be created if the base table is non-existant.  On the converse side, there are some statements that otherwise complete (aliases), which may give other programs ideas about the state of the database  which (because of new errors) simply isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to quit after an error ? Here is a few examples. Be sure to check documentation of [WHENEVER SQLERROR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#i2700066).

DDL (DML) example:

```
prompt continues after error
prompt =====================
prompt

create table foo;

prompt quits after error with error code 
prompt =================================
prompt

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

create table foo;

prompt never gets here
prompt ===============
prompt

quit
```

PL/SQL subprogram raises an exception:

```
create or replace function foo return number as
  foo_error exception;
begin
  raise foo_error;
end;
/
show errors

prompt continues after error
prompt =====================
prompt

select foo from dual;

prompt quits after error with error code 
prompt =================================
prompt

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

select foo from dual;

prompt never gets here
prompt ===============
prompt

quit
```

PL/SQL unit compilation fails:

```
create or replace procedure compile_function (f in varchar2) as
begin
  execute immediate 'alter function :f compile' using f;
exception
  when others then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Failed to compile function ' || f);
end;
/
show errors

prompt continues after error
prompt =====================
prompt

create or replace function foo return number as
begin
  compilation will fail
end;
/
show errors

exec compile_function('foo')

prompt quits after error with error code 
prompt =================================
prompt

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

create or replace function foo return number as
begin
  compilation will fail
end;
/
show errors

exec compile_function('foo')

prompt never gets here
prompt ===============
prompt

quit
```